# Recover lost MySQL database on OSX?

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I am using a MySQL database on macOS. I created a MY SQL SERVER  from System preferences and connected to it via MYSQL Workbench.

After some time, I want create a new connection to that database and I forgot the password of `root` user. I `Initialize` another database from System Preferences, Stop and Start the Server.

When I log in via a new connection to database, My old data was lost. There is a way to recover old data?

Please, Anyone meet that problem before?

Comment: You can use your TimeMachine backup to restore the database files that were previously stored in the mysql data directory. So stop your server, go into the database directory, and restore the content of the directory to the previous state. And then you just need to reset the root password using the command line.

Comment: Time Machine was disabled

Comment: @GabyFitcal Did you manage to find your db somehow?

Comment: @M.JunaidSalaat unfortunately not. Sorry. I tried with some tools to recover lost data, but nothing useful

Comment: Same happened to me. Very important work has been lost, because database wasn't saved elsewhere. MacOS should have more clear and bold explanation, that all MySQL Data will be deleted at this point!